# How Do I Add Active Directory To APIM Using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-api-management

Following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad#authorize-developer-accounts-by-using-azure-ad) you can link Azure API Management to Users/Groups in Azure Active Directory.

At the moment I am creating the APIM instance with [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/api_management.html)

```
resource "azurerm_api_management" "test" {
  name                = "example-apim"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  publisher_name      = "My Company"
  publisher_email     = "company@terraform.io"

  sku {
    name     = "Developer"
    capacity = 1
  }
}
```

How do I add the Active Directory Identity Provider to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform added support for this in [December 2019](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/5268)

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_identity_provider_aad

You can now link it with:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_aad" "example" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  client_id           = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  client_secret       = "00000000000000000000000000000000"
  allowed_tenants     = ["00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be possible with terraform, however, it can be added by [calling the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/identityprovider/createorupdate) from the Azure CLI.

```
az rest -m put -u "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/my-apim/identityProviders/aad?api-version=2019-01-01" -b "{'properties':{'clientId':'xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx','clientSecret':'super-secret-password','allowedTenants':['mysite.com']}}"
```

The body `-b` is json that has been formatted to a single line.

You need to look up the `clientId` from active directory and know what the `clientSecret` is.

You can embedd this command in terraform if you wish:

```
resource "null_resource" "add-ad-identity-provider" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az rest -m put -u \"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/my-apim/identityProviders/aad?api-version=2019-01-01\" -b \"{'properties':{'clientId':'xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx','clientSecret':'super-secret-password','allowedTenants':['mysite.com']}}\""
  }
  depends_on = ["azurerm_api_management.test"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the original answer from March 4th mostly works.  However, a piece is missing. You also need to set up an app registration via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad
That supplies the answers you need (Other than the allowed tenants, which is the tenant-id's to allow).

And that is also missing a piece, which is to, when configurating the app registration, to also go to API Permissions, add a new permission for Azure Active Directory Graph (in supported legacy APIs), create an Application permission, and add Directory.Read.All.  Then grant admin consent.

Answer (score 0):

If you combine resources from both `azurerm` and `azuread` providers, you can now automate the process of deploying APIM with an app registration and AAD authentication on the developer portal. It covers these two guides from Microsoft:

- [Quickstart: Create a new Azure API Management service instance by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/get-started-create-service-instance)
- [Authorize developer accounts by using Azure Active Directory in Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad)

Terraform code example:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">=1.0.9"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.81.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "=2.7.0"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "azuread" {}

resource "azurerm_api_management" "api_management" {
  name                = var.api_management_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  publisher_name      = var.publisher_name
  publisher_email     = var.publisher_email
  sku_name            = var.api_management_sku

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azuread_application" "application" {
  display_name = var.application_name
  web {
    redirect_uris = ["${azurerm_api_management.api_management.developer_portal_url}/"]
  }
}

resource "azuread_application_password" "password" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.application.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_aad" "identity_provider_aad" {
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.api_management.name
  client_id           = azuread_application.application.application_id
  client_secret       = azuread_application_password.password.value
  allowed_tenants     = var.id_provider_allowed_tenants
}
```